# Wowza breaks mp4 after reconnect

Tags: wowza

On our server we have Wowza 4.0.4.

My case:

1. Start stream (e.g 10sec)
2. Disconnect from Internet
3. Reconnect
4. End stream

As result I get two mp4 files (before and after disconnect) but the first one (before disconnect) is broken, the second one is OK.

How can I fix Wowza to get the first mp4 file normal/unbroken?